# How to restore matrix from its CSR representation?

Tags: python, math, matrix, linear-algebra

I don't get the algorithm behind restoring a matrix from its csr representation. For example i've got these 3 arrays:

```py
data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 11]
ind = [0, 1, 3, 2, 1,  3]
indptr  = [0, 3, 4, 6]
```

the matrix we are representing:

```py
[[1, 2, 0, 3],
 [0, 0, 4, 0],
 [0, 1, 0, 11]]
```

what do i have to do to restore second matrix from these 3 arrays without any external libraries?

Comment: `what do i have to do to restore second matrix from` - figure out the logic/process required then implement.  Which part are you having trouble with - can you write the logic/process in words? Did your implementation go awry? Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page

Comment: @wwii i literally asked for an algorithm behind this "process". everything you need to know is in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`indptr` is *saying* that

- the first row is *comprised of* items 0,1,2 of `data` and `ind` - slice(**0**,**3**)
- the second row is *comprised of* item 3 of `data` and `ind` - slice(**3**,**4**)
- the third row is *comprised of* items 4,5 of `data` and `ind` - slice(**4**,**6**)

This *csr* is only telling you where non-zero values are - `ind` is the index of a non-zero value and `data` is the value at that index.

The first row has

- non-zero data at indices 0,1,3 - `ind[slice(0,3)]`
- the data at those indices is 1,2,3 - `data[slice(0,3)]`
- notice index 2 is missing - it must be zero

There is no indication of the size/dimensions of the matrix except that there are only three rows with non-zero data (gleaned from `indptr`) and that the largest index for any row is three so there must be four columns.